# How to label a graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created a Matlab plot with two graphs within one figure. I have plotted the graphs in colour and set up a legend. But now, I want the graph to be understandable in black and white print as well. Therefore, I want to label the graphs directly. 
I have tried:

```
text(P_in,P_out,{'AM/AM'});
```

But this, clearly doesn't work. 
Here is the figure: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place text in a graph, use

```
text(x, y, 'Example text')
```

where `x`, `y` are numbers between `0` and `1` specifying the text position within the current axes.

You can also use

```
gtext('Example text')
```

and select the text position with the mouse.

Comment: Or `annotation`